# How to write a karma-Jasmine test for a dynamic configuration file JSON

Tags: json, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am very new to writing tests in Karma and Jasmine. In my case, I have a dynamic configuration file that loads before the app is initialized and that file is a JSON with a value.

configuration.json

```
{
    "sampleConfigValue": "this is a sample value from config"
}
```

Configuration.ts

```
export interface Configuration {
    sampleConfigValue: string;
}
```

ConfigurationService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigurationService {
  private configData: any | undefined;
  private readonly configPath: string = '../assets/demo/data/config.json';
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  async loadConfiguration(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get(`${this.configPath}`)
        .toPromise().then(res => this.configData = res);     
      return this.configData;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  }

  get config(): Configuration | undefined {
    return this.configData;
  }
}
```

Exporting the ConfigurationLoader in app.module.ts

```
export function configLoader(injector: Injector) : () => Promise<any>
{
    return () => injector.get(ConfigurationService).loadConfiguration(); 
}
```

and Provider in app.module.ts

```
{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configLoader, deps: [Injector], multi: true},
```

configuration.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ConfigurationService } from './configuration.service';

describe('ConfigurationService', () => {
  let service: ConfigurationService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(ConfigurationService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The configuration file is working but I am wondering how to write a test case for this dynamic configuration in my project?

Your time and help will really help me :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unit testing, you're supposed to test a code unit and mock the rest.

So create a mock then test :

```js
// Put this in the main describe
const returnValue = {};
let httpMock: { get: jasmine.Spy };
let service: ConfigurationService;

// Put this in the main beforeEach
httpMock = {
  get: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(returnValue)),
};
service = new ConfigurationService(<any>httpMock);

// Make a meaningful test
it('Should call the endpoint and retrieve the config', (done) => {
  service.loadConfiguration().then(() => {
    expect(httpMock.get)
      .toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(service['configPath']);
    expect(service['configData']).toBe(returnValue);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Should I create this code in config.service.spec.ts file? or make another file as spec?

Comment: You can put this in your existing spec file, remove everything in the main describe as you won't need it anymore

Comment: It shows this error on get: ' Type '{ get: jasmine.Spy<jasmine.Func>; }' is not assignable to type 'Spy<Func>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'get' does not exist in type 'Spy<Func>'

Comment: Sorry, edited the code (`let httpMock`)

Comment: Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ get: Spy<Func>; }'. I am sorry but I am new to this.

Comment: Should I give configPath of JSON file there in service['configPath']?

Comment: Typo on my end this time ... Edited again (`expect(httpMock.get)`)

Comment: No you should not, that's the purpose of mocking

Comment: Now it says in  browser: Expected undefined to equal Object({  }).

Comment: New edit, I thought I could get away with asynchronous code but obviously not, should be good !

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Can you suggest me the course or website link where I can study to improve my test skills for angular?

Comment: Honestly, I would love to, but I do not know any. I learned all of my testing knowledge on the field, and most of the courses you will take will tell you to use the `TestBed` (which is not necessary at all, even discouraged). I'd say start on the official documentation first ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245783/discussion-between-ftslaptop-pc-and-temp-user).